# Resize image based on memory size

Tags: imagemagick

I need to resize image based on memory.

What I am getting is following option in "convert" command.

```
-resize 800x600
-resize 25%
```

Is there any command like -

```
-resize 10KB
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
convert input.jpg -define jpeg:extent=300kb ... output.jpg
```

---

If you want a way to do something similar with Python, I wrote an answer that works pretty well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52281257/2836621). It does a binary search for a JPEG quality that satisfies a maximum size requirement.

Comment: Hi Mark, 
It is not giving desired output :<br>
convert vik.jpg -define jpeg:extent=10kb out.jpg<br>
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 22920 Oct  3 00:17 vik.jpg<br>
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 25144 Oct 29 19:40 out.jpg<br>

Comment: It may not be possible for such a small size. Try adding `-strip` too. And try larger sizes too.