# How to determine the scale factor of image if I want an exact size in bytes

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, image-manipulation

So I would like to store images which are uploaded to an API. However there is a constraint that I don't store images above `1MB`, but resize them in order to be lower than `1MB`.

I have a very basic formula for this:
`resizeFactor = MAX_IMAGE_SIZE_IN_BYTES/currentImageSizeinBytes`

Then I do this:

```
 Image image = Image.Load(stream);
 image.Mutate(x => x.Resize((int)(image.Width*resizeFactor), 0));
```

Now this resizes every image to be under `1MB`, but in case of some images they are way more under `1MB`, for example an example jpg has `1,785,213 bytes`, the resize factor is `0.58` for this, so the result image will be `641,188 bytes`.

If I could be able to resize an image to exact `1e^6` bytes +- `50 bytes`, would that save more image quality? So with exact example if I could resize the above image from `1.7MB` to `1MB` instead of `600kB`, would it save more image quality?

If yes, how could I resize my images to be very close to `1MB`?

Comment: What language are you using? What framework? Are images JPEG or PNG?

Comment: Note that a megabyte is 1MB, whereas 1mb is a millibit or 8 billion times smaller. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte#:~:text=The%20megabyte%20is%20a%20multiple,one%20million%20bytes%20of%20information.

Comment: I am using ASP.NET C#, with .NET 8. Images are mostly JPEGs. Thank you for the info about millibits, however I think it is obvious what I am talking about now.

Comment: Your *"resize factor"* is not going to work that well as the compressibility of images depends on their content and is often not very linear. If you use **ImageMagick** to resize JPEGs, you can specify the desired maximum size like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26632460/2836621 If you are using PNGs, I wrote an approach here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71205362/2836621

Comment: Note that there are current .NET bindings available for ImageMagick.

Comment: *how could I resize my images to be very close to 1mb?* - by trial and error with the generation parameters, on every image you put through